# How to pass bytes32[] array to call this function using web3 js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, bytes32

I have a function

```
function multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked
    (
        ERC20 _token,
        bytes32[] _addressesAndAmounts
    ) public
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < _addressesAndAmounts.length; i++) {
            address to = address(_addressesAndAmounts[i] >> 96);
            uint amount = uint(uint96(_addressesAndAmounts[i]));
            _safeERC20Transfer(_token, to, amount);
            MultiERC20Transfer(msg.sender, to, amount, _token);
        }
    }
```

For exmple I want to call this function with `_addressesAndAmounts` of `0x2970c57fe5264caf1689bc129b41bd7ddf06b4f7 10`, and `0x63F69E69857dc198AE63C1BeEe26803c50C00813 10`, how can I pass these as parameter to call this function?

```js
  const multisendTx = await contract.methods. multiERC20TransferTightlyPacked(tokenAddress, addressesAmounts).encodeABI();
```

How should I make the `addressesAmounts`?

on the solidity code it says:

```
address to = address(_addressesAndAmounts[i] >> 96);
uint amount = uint(uint96(_addressesAndAmounts[i]));
```

I don't know what does `>> 96` mean how does it work in js?

Comment: Please specify your web3.js version.

Comment: Also, from your code, it doesn't look like you need a `bytes32` to begin with, since `uint256` seems reasonable enough here.

Comment: I'm using web3@1.2.6

Comment: what do you mean by that `uint256` is reasonable enough?

Comment: Is this function in your own contract, or in someone else's contract that you need to interact with?

Comment: It's contract I deployed from someone's code https://github.com/Alonski/MultiSendEthereum

Comment: deployed the contract here https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x39855acd89d197f53d15514175f2a43c23686bf9#tokentxns

Comment: So you can change that `bytes32` to `uint256` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

const toBN = Web3.utils.toBN;

function getArray(items) {
    return items.map(item => "0x" + toBN(item.address).shln(96).or(toBN(item.amount)).toString(16));
}
```

For example:

```
const array = getArray([
    {address: "0x2970c57fe5264caf1689bc129b41bd7ddf06b4f7", amount: "10"},
    {address: "0x63F69E69857dc198AE63C1BeEe26803c50C00813", amount: "10"},
]);

console.log(array);
```

The value of `amount` should be at most 2 ^ 96 - 1 of course.

Its type is `string` because it can be larger than 2 ^ 53 - 1 (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`).

Comment: oh so, basically it needs an array of address/amount object, thank you very much, I will try this. and get back to you.

Comment: @bbnn: No! The contract function takes an array of `bytes32` elements. I gave you a JS helper function to create that array.

Comment: ok, so the `array` is the `addressesAmounts` right

Comment: It's still the same... The transaction got executed successfully with 0 amount value, but reverted with non-0 amount.. I wonder what is wrong..

is there anyway to debug these between executed and execution failure event logs? executed: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xfea8ab49ceaaf69011db45cf7ac78eff29aebe8982ae26811c5027d7dc32813b#eventlog reverted: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x550375df362098b67f4f6327c7e4bcdb5dd7ef9ef13a982e64ab42f16bc272b9#eventlog

Comment: @bbnn: Same as what? You asked how to pass a proper input to your contract function, and I gave you an answer. What has that got to do with whether or not the function reverts for some input? There is no such context in your question relating for specific input behavior of the function. If you have a revert issue on some specific input, then I auggest that you post it as a separate question.

Comment: same with my previous question, I think you were in there too. But yes, you taught me how to make bytes[] in this context. Thank you!